# Inserting text to the same row but multiple columns Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, multiple-columns

I am new to VBA and I know that strikethrough is a text format which I believe that it can't be used in a blank cell.

Is there a more efficient method to insert "-" to the same row but multiple columns from "D" to "G"?

Please have a look at my coding:

```
Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "D")
Insert.Value = "-"

Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "E")
Insert.Value = "-"

Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "F")
Insert.Value = "-"

Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "G")
Insert.Value = "-"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options. One is to set the `StrikeThrough` property to True then fill the cells with a handful of spaces. Or you can just enter a handful of hyphens if led with an apostrophe.

Something like:

```
Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "D").Resize(, 4).Font.StrikeThrough = True
Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "D").Resize(, 4).Value = "          "
```

OR:

```
Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, "D").Resize(, 4).Value = "'-------"
```

Answer (score 2):

Excel permits strikethrough text, and set it as a format on blank cells.
 Refer MS Documentation: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Format-text-as-strikethrough-163dd4e8-f413-4474-9c42-aaee8828d647

For insert part of "-" you can use looping method instead of writing each line for a column/row.

```
' example
For counter = 1 To 10
    Sheets(1).Range("A" & counter).Value = "-"
Next
```

But it seems ms documentation will help much more.

Comment: I understand that excel permits strikethrough text, but I need a strikethrough on a blank cell which is not possible unless I write something to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim CashRowName As Long, Insert As Range
    CashRowName = 6
    Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Range("D" & CashRowName & ":G" & CashRowName)
    Insert.Value = "-"
End Sub
```

*(Personally, I would change the name of the `Long` variable to CashRowNumber)*

**EDIT#1:**

If some of the cells in the range had text and some were empty and you want to use strikethrough font on the filled cells and insert a dash in the empty cells, then before:

[image]

the new macro:

```
Sub dural2()
    Dim CashRowName As Long, Insert As Range
    Dim cel As Range

    CashRowName = 6
    Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Range("D" & CashRowName & ":G" & CashRowName)

    For Each cel In Insert
        cel.Font.Strikethrough = True
        If cel.Value = "" Then
            cel.Value = "-"
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

and after:

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This really is a new to me!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to loop through the columns by referencing them based on their column number:

```vb
Public Sub DashOutRow(CashRowName as String)
  Dim i as Long
  Dim Insert as Excel.Range

  For i = 4 to 7 'D - G
    Set Insert = Sheets("Cash").Cells(CashRowName, i)
    Insert.Value = "'-"
  Next
End Sub
```

You can make this more flexible by making the sheet name a variable, or the column range variable (for example).

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for providing your help!